# pytorch customdataset notimplemented error

Tags: pytorch

Im making my own custom datasets in pytorch.

AND, I would like to visualize the image.

however, i think something wrong is happening in custom datasets.

Please help me.

> NotImplementedError                       Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in ()
> 1 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
> 2 dat= TrainDataset(transforms.ToTensor())
> ----> 3 img,label= dat[i]
> 4 plt.imshow(img.permute(1,2,0))
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/utils/data/dataset.py in
> **getitem**(self, index)
> 31
> 32     def **getitem**(self, index) -> T_co:
> ---> 33         raise NotImplementedError
> 34
> 35     def **add**(self, other: 'Dataset[T_co]') -> 'ConcatDataset[T_co]':
>
> NotImplementedError:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim
import torchvision.transforms as transforms
import torchvision
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
import os
import glob

from torch.utils.data import Dataset

import pandas as pd
from PIL import Image


class TrainDataset(Dataset):
  def __init__(self, transform):
    super().__init__()
    self.data = pd.read_csv('/content/drive/MyDrive/cancer/train_labels.csv')
    self.transform = transform
    
    def __len__(self):
      return len(self.data)

    def __getitem__(self,idx):
      img_name, label = self.data.iloc[idx]
      img = Image.open(f'/content/drive/MyDrive/cancer/test/{image_name}.tif')
      img = self.transform(img)
      return (img, torch.tensor(label).long())



import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
dat= TrainDataset(transforms.ToTensor())
img,label= dat[1]
plt.imshow(img.permute(1,2,0))
```

Comment: Well from a single glance i can't tell whats wrong, everything seems fine but i notice your init has wrong indentation, it might be the formatting problem?

Comment: https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/getting-notimplementederror-to-loading-coustom-dataset/50629, you can take a look here but it seems it was the indentation problem